# Dynamics 365 Plugin SDK throwing exception when updating a strongly typed entiy in sandbox mode

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I'm an learning Dynamics 365 plugin development.

**Problem:** When invoking the Update method on a strongly typed entity, I an getting a exception. The exact error message is:

"System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #1330ADC1"

**My Setup:**
My solution contains a simple plugin. I have created a strongly typed entity Account. The plugin's Isolation mode is Sandbox. Telephone1 field is a string.

I retrieve the Account from CRM, then update the Telephone1 field to a new value and update the Account record. Simple :)

**Code:**

```
public class PostOperationaccountUpdate: IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var organisationService = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (IOrganizationService)) as IOrganizationService;
        var context = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (IPluginExecutionContext)) as IPluginExecutionContext;

        var entityAccount = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
        var id = entityAccount.Id;

        var account = organisationService.Retrieve("account", id, new ColumnSet("telephone1"));

        //Get a strongly typed version of the Account entity
        var dbAccount = account.ToEntity<Account>();

        //Update the telephone1 field using the "old" way
        account["telephone1"] = "1234567890";

        try
        {
            //This will pass
            organisationService.Update(account);

            //Update the strongly typed Account
            dbAccount.Telephone1 = "plop";

            //This fails
            organisationService.Update(dbAccount);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**What have I tried:**
-> I have changed the plugin's Isolation mode to None - this works! According to the best practices, it isn't recommended

Thanks for the help
Charles

Comment: Does it work in the sandbox if you make it late bound ?

Comment: Is the strongly typed Account class in a different DLL by chance?  If so, I believe you'll have to ilmerge it into the plugin DLL.  You could quickly test that out by adding the Account.cs class directly into your plugins project.

Comment: @Alex: Yes. If I make I make it late bound and sandbox it, it does work

Comment: @Polshgiant: Nope. It is all in one project.

Comment: I am assuming your early bound class does have the attribute `[assembly: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ProxyTypesAssemblyAttribute()]`? Serialization exceptions are also caused if the proxy type isn't enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SerializationException` occurs when you mix early-bound types with code expecting late-bound types, [here the MSDN gives some degree of explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328263.aspx#bkmk_useearlybound).

Essentially, the exception occurs when you require the platform to convert between early-bound and late-bound types.

`Update` expects a late-bound type

```
organisationService.Update(dbAccount); // dbAccount should be an 'Entity' object
```

and this causes the exception.

I never use early-bound types so I can't reliably tell how to fix your code, but the following MSDN articles should be useful:

- [Update an entity record using early-bound entity classes and the OrganizationServiceContext class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328499.aspx#update)
- [Sample: Create, retrieve, update, and delete records (early bound)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334754.aspx)

Comment: `Update` expects an object of the type `Entity` --> `public virtual void Update(Entity entity);`. Late bound or early bound the internal type is `entity`, all early bound does is, in the background, sets an attribute value with the correct crm data type and also flattens data during retrieves. I use `organisationService.Update(entity);` with both early and late bound objects. Late or early bound, both are objects of the type `Entity` and creates and updates should work interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That has got me thinking - I will refactor my code.

Appreciate the help!